# Display dynamic message in dialog box

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a form containing a save command button. On clicking save, a dialog box is open with contain : 2 button (Ok and Cancel) , message. I want to display a dynamic message in the dialog box. Can someone help how to do this?
Note that on clicking on 'Ok' button, it redirects the user on another page. This part is working fine. I need to display the dynamic message in the dialog box.

```
<h:form>
        <p:commandButton value="Save" update="confirmSave1" action="#{TestComponent.saveTest(TestComponent.test)}">             
        <p:confirm header="TESTING" icon="ui-icon-alert" confirmMessage="TESTEST" />                
        </p:commandButton>
        <p:confirmDialog global="true" id="confirmSave1" widgetVar="confirmSave">
        <p:commandButton value="Save" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" action="#{TestComponent.redirectURL()}">
        <p:ajax event="click" listener="#{TestComponent.redirectURL()}" />
        </p:commandButton>
        <p:commandButton value="Cancel" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
        </p:confirmDialog>
</h:form>
```

Comment: dynamic message for what ?! and why ?!

Comment: I have a drop down list in my form. The value selected from drop down, should appear in the dialog box. So on clicking save, it will prompt the user the selected value from the dropdown list. Depending on the value, the user will click on save or cancel.

Comment: the widget documentation shows an example on how to customize the confirmDialog message and header - http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/confirmDialog.xhtml

Comment: Please post your jsf code or at least your drop down list code.